# Plot different parts of a vector with different colors on the same graph

Tags: r, plot, colors

As from the title suppose this vector and plot:

`plot(rnorm(200,5,2),type="l")`

This returns this plot

[image]

What i would like to know is whether there is a way to make the first half of it to be in blue `col="blue"` and the rest of it to be in red `"col="red"`.

Similar question BUT in Matlab not R: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45505927/ploting-a-wave-with-different-colors-in-the-same-figure)

Comment: Not sure if this is important, but all the previous solutions erocoar and I provided created two disconnected line segments. If you want to seek solution plotting lines without discrete segments, I have updated my post with a workaround to plot continuous line using `ggplot2`.

Comment: That is excellent! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a base R solution, but I think this is how to plot it using [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2). It is necessary to prepare a data frame to plot the data.

```
set.seed(1234)

vec <- rnorm(200,5,2)

dat <- data.frame(Value = vec)
dat$Group <- as.character(rep(c(1, 2), each = 100))
dat$Index <- 1:200

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Index, y = Value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = Group)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

We can also use the [lattice](/questions/tagged/lattice) package with the same data frame.

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(Value ~ Index, data = dat, type = 'l', groups = Group, col = c("blue", "red"))
```

[image]

Notice that the blue line and red line are disconnected. Not sure if this is important, but if you want to plot a continuous line, here is a workaround in [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2). The idea is to subset the data frame for the second half, plot the entire data frame with color as blue, and then plot the second data frame with color as red.

```
dat2 <- dat[dat$Index %in% 101:200, ]

ggplot(dat, aes(x = Index, y = Value)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue") +
  geom_line(data = dat2, aes(x = Index, y = Value), color = "red") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: it does give me this `Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric` which is for `dat2` of being class numeric.

Comment: @HerculesApergis This post could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29953011/in-r-dealing-with-error-ggplot2-doesnt-know-how-to-deal-with-data-of-class-nu

Comment: Aaa fixed it! figured out, i have made a silly mistake when i typed it in.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use lines for the second half:

```
dat <- rnorm(200, 5, 2)
plot(1:100, dat[1:100], col = "blue", type = "l", xlim = c(0, 200), ylim = c(min(dat), max(dat)))
lines(101:200, dat[101:200], col = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: hmm i see. I guess through the base R it has to be done in different parts combined. Thank you!