# Plot with different colour variables and average line in R

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I have a dataset in `R` of values in `[-1,1]` for 5 countries, namely `(A,B,C,D,E)` as follows:

```
data <- matrix(runif(n=50, min = -1, max = 1),ncol = 5)
data <- round(data,2)
colnames(data) <-
  c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
```

Then I calculate the average value of each row for all countries with the following:

```
aver <- as.matrix(rowMeans(data))
rownames(aver) <- c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6","X7","X8","X9","X10")
```

I want to create a plot with the observations with each country (column) to have different colors and the `aver` line to be included. I am using the following but can not make it properly work.

```
plot(c(data),col=c("red","yellow","green","blue","black"))
lines(aver)
```

The final result must look like this but with colored observations included:[image]

How can I do that??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487713/plot-different-parts-of-a-vector-with-different-colors-on-the-same-graph

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot different parts of a vector with different colors on the same graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48487713/plot-different-parts-of-a-vector-with-different-colors-on-the-same-graph)

Comment: Try `matplot(data,col=c("red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "black"), type="l", lty=1, lwd=2)` and `abline(h=aver, col=c("red", "yellow", "green", "blue", "black"), lwd=2, lty=3)`.

Comment: @dcarlson that is close to what I am looking for, however (i) How can I make the observations to be seen just like bullets, and (ii) Why there are so many lines in the abline command? I updated the picture of what I am looking for

Comment: @AmitGupta this is not what I am looking for, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
matplot(as.data.frame(data),col=c("red","yellow","green","blue","black"), pch=16, ylab = "")
lines(aver)
```

Output:

[image]

Add this for legend:

```
legend("bottomright", legend = colnames(data)[1:5], col=c("red","yellow","green","blue","black"), pch = 16)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to display the colours as labels next to the graph? i.e., (black dot): country E?

Comment: @nickolakis, check updated post!